# Application is not available in Google Play Store for some devices

Tags: android

My application does appear in google play for all devices except Samsung Tablet 3.

My manifest permissions:

```
  <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
            android:required="false" >
    </uses-feature>
```

Do i need to change those permission?

When i add the apk, i can see that i use those features:

android.hardware.CAMERA

android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS

android.hardware.LOCATION

android.hardware.location.GPS

android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE

android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT

android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN

**The problem: When i search the app form google play application from my Samsung Tablet 3 is that the app is not available in Google Play Store for this device.**

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2011/02/best-practices-for-honeycomb-and.html

Comment: I'm unsure if your tablet supports `android.hardware.telephony`

Comment: i added android:required="false" to android.hardware.telephony, this will fix the problem no?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the question is if the tablet has AutoFocus. The last few Samsung Tablets I was on did not have Autofocus.

Answer (score 0):

Some devices do not have gps functinality so if your app uses gps, the appstore will asume it is not useful on some devices which do not have the required capability.

Answer (score 0):

Its truely the Manifest Permission

android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS
android.hardware.location.GPS

If the device has no autofocus or no GPS funktion its not displayed in google play.