# Some Android device can't search and allow to run my app in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, device

My team upped an android app to Google Play. However, we using some android device and search our app but it can't. If we visit Google Play by link, Google show me that the app is not available in Google Play Store for this device.

My manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.ntq.idi"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="2446"
    android:versionName="1.0.2446" >
    
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="false"
                  android:smallScreens = "true"
                  android:normalScreens = "true"
                  android:largeScreens = "true"
                  android:xlargeScreens = "true"
                  android:anyDensity = "true"/>
    
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> -->
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.ntq.idi.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="" />
        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".GCMIntentService"
            android:enabled="true" />
        <service android:name=".services.ServiceHelper" />
        <service android:name="" >
        </service>
        <service android:name="" >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I used some suggest from here but it not work:
[Application is not available in Google Play Store for some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365543/application-is-not-available-in-google-play-store-for-some-devices)

Here's some way i manage to do:

> remove: android:installLocation="preferExternal" it can't help.
>
> change:  but it can't help

Here are some device not work for me: Nexus 7 2012, HTC Desire C, Sony Xperia Tipo...

The answer from google support:

> Hi,
>
> Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support. I investigated
> the behavior that you've reported and have found that your app is not
> compatible with the Nexus 7 (grouper) due to a conflict with the
> following: android.hardware.camera. While I'm able to use our tools to
> determine the conflict, I don't have any additional insight into why
> certain devices conflict with specific permissions and features.
>
> For questions related to app development, I recommend visiting our
> developer site to review documentation for most technical
> development-related questions at
> http://developer.android.com/support.html.
>
> Here you can find links to developer support forums and IRC chat
> communities where developers help each other solve development-related
> issues.
>
> I hope this helps. If you have any further questions, please let me
> know.

Comment: I dont think Nexus 7 has camera (rear facing), so use-feature camera will probably fail on it. Others I am not sure

Comment: I thought that too but my HTC Desire A8181 have both front-camera and back-camera.

Comment: have you tried to remove `android:resizeable` since it's deprecated according to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: Ok! Let me try it late. If that Ok i will notice you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing uses-feature one by one and check.
You can add check for feature in code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution of mr.kevin and it work. Great thank you.

This is the answer from google support:

Hi,

Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support. I investigated the behavior that you've reported and have found that your app is not compatible with the Nexus 7 (grouper) due to a conflict with the following: android.hardware.camera. While I'm able to use our tools to determine the conflict, I don't have any additional insight into why certain devices conflict with specific permissions and features.

For questions related to app development, I recommend visiting our developer site to review documentation for most technical development-related questions at http://developer.android.com/support.html.

Here you can find links to developer support forums and IRC chat communities where developers help each other solve development-related issues.

I hope this helps. If you have any further questions, please let me know.